# How to fix "ImportError: cannot import name 'Socrata'" error in Python when using sodapy client?

Tags: python

I'm trying to use the sodapy client but am getting this error: ImportError: cannot import name 'Socrata.'

I've used the client in the past but recently got a new computer. I installed the most recent version of Python (3.7.3). I realized sodapy only supports Python versions 2.7 to 3.6.

I downloaded Python 3.6.5 and created a conda environment that uses Python 3.6.5. I installed sodapy as well as future and requests which were listed as requirements for the sodapy client. However, I'm still receiving the "ImportError: cannot import name 'Socrata'" error.

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is happening.  Edit the question to show the full error traceback message

Comment: Did you name your local program `sodapy.py`?